# Trying to get property 'Nom' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have some errors in my code, I would like the search box to work when I put the name, the specialty and the city, but it doesn't work anymore, so this is my **controller code:**

```
 public function chercher (Request $request) {
    $doctors=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    $rech=$request->get('rech');
    $spec=$request->get('spec');
    $ville=$request->get('Région');


     $S=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() 
     ->where('Spécialité',$spec) ;
     $SV=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()
     ->where('Spécialité',$spec) 
     ->where('Ville',$ville);        
     $SN=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() 
     ->where('Spécialité',$spec) 
     ->where('Nom',$rech) ;
     $SNV=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() 
     ->where('Spécialité',$spec) 
     ->where('Nom',$rech) 
     ->where('Ville',$ville);
     $V=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() 
     ->where('Ville',$ville);
     $N=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() 
     ->where('Nom',$rech);
     $NV=medecin::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() 
     ->where('Nom',$rech) 
     ->where('Ville',$ville) ; 
     return view ('doctors' ,['doc'=> $doctors,$S,$SV,$SN,$SNV,$V,$N,$NV],['tab'=>[$rech,$spec,$ville]]); }
```

and this is the **view:**

```
{{$tab[0]}}
{{$tab[1]}}
{{$tab[2]}}
 <ul>
  @if($tab[1]=='Dentiste' && $tab[2]=='Tunis' && $tab[0]=='' )  
    @foreach($doc[0] as $show)
<h1> Dr.{{$show->Nom}} {{$show->Prénom}}  </h1> </br>
 <h1> {{$show->Photo}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Spécialité}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Ville}}</h1>
@endforeach
 @elseif($tab[1]=='' && $tab[2]=='' ) 
   @foreach($doc[2] as $show)
   <h1> Dr.{{$show->Nom}} {{$show->Prénom}}  </h1> </br>
 <h1> {{$show->Photo}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Spécialité}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Ville}}</h1>
@endforeach
@elseif ($tab[0]=='' && $tab[2]='')
@foreach ($doc[7] as $show)
<h1> {{$show->Nom}} {{$show->Prénom}}  </h1> </br>
 <h1> {{$show->Photo}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Spécialité}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Ville}}</h1>
@endforeach
@elseif ($tab[0]=='' && $tab[1]='')
@foreach ($doc[3] as $show) 
<h1> {{$show->Nom}} {{$show->Prénom}}  </h1> </br>
 <h1> {{$show->Photo}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Spécialité}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Ville}}</h1>
@endforeach
@elseif ($tab[1]=='' )
@foreach ($doc[1] as $show)
<h1> {{$show->Nom}} {{$show->Prénom}}  </h1> </br> 
 <h1> {{$show->Photo}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Spécialité}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Ville}}</h1>
@endforeach
@elseif ($tab[0]=='' )
@foreach ($doc[6] as $show)
<h1> {{$show->Nom}} {{$show->Prénom}}  </h1> </br>
 <h1> {{$show->Photo}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Spécialité}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Ville}}</h1>
@endforeach
@else ($tab[2]=='' )
@foreach ($doc[5] as $show)
 <h1> {{$show->Nom}} {{$show->Prénom}}  </h1> </br>  <h1> {{$show->Photo}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Spécialité}} </h1>
<h1>{{$show->Ville}}</h1>
@endforeach -->

@endif
</ul> 
</div>
</body>
```

if I click on the search button, this error appears:

> **Trying to get property 'Nom' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Doctor\resources\views\doctors.blade.php)**

Comment: `['doc'=> $doctors,$S,$SV,$SN,$SNV,$V,$N,$NV]` Did you mean `['doc'=> [$doctors,$S,$SV,$SN,$SNV,$V,$N,$NV]]`?

Comment: Hello @Ghoff, can you please check and (if it works, which I'm pretty sure it will) accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view,

```
@foreach($doc[0] as $show)
```

should be

```
@foreach($doc as $show)
```

because you should be iterating on the array of doctors.

By doing

```
@foreach($doc[0] as $show)
```

you are instead iterating over the properties of one single doctor object, which is not what you want.

Comment: @NicoHaase done.
OP, can you please accept this as the answer?